# How to use value from localStorage in Django template?

Tags: javascript, python, django, web

How can I use a value from a localStorage in a django template rendering?

for example:

```
<div class="one two {% if localStorage.hidden %}hidden{% endif %}">Some content</div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't think django, running on the server, would have access to a browsers Storage.

Comment: i think you should use JS instead

Comment: You need to write some javascript to access it; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage